# How to compare condition multile table in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, multiple-tables

how can i compare multiple table while checking condition in MySQL?

**Cheque** Table1

```
--------------------------
date       |  Cheque_no
--------------------------
10/10/2015 | 09876543
--------------------------
17/10/2015 | 45678990
--------------------------
```

**Payment** Table2

```
----------------------------------------
date       |  Cheque_no  | Amount_Paid
----------------------------------------
10/10/2015 | 09876543    |   1000
----------------------------------------
```

And I am using the following query:

```
select * from Cheque,Payment where Cheque.Cheque_no != Payment .Cheque_no
```

I am Expecting the output is

```
17/10/2015 | 45678990
```

Comment: `SELECT some stuff FROM somewhere LEFT JOIN somewhere else ON something = something else WHERE something else IS NULL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a simple `not in` condition would do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM   cheque
WHERE  cheque_no NOT IN (SELECT cheque_no FROM payment)
```